# How to reference sub-objects in talend schema

Tags: salesforce, talend, soql

So I have the following SOQL query that includes the `ActivityHistories` relationship of the `Account` object:

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, (SELECT Description FROM ActivityHistories) 
  FROM Account 
  WHERE Name = '<some client>'
```

This query works just in in [SOQLXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/) and returns 5 nested rows under the ActivityHistories key. In Talend, I am following the instructions from [this page](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tSalesforceInput) to access the sub-objects (although the example uses the query "up" syntax, not the query "down" syntax. My schema mapping is as follows:
[image: Talend schema mapping]

The query returns the parent `Account` rows but not the `ActivityHistory` rows that are in the subquery:

```
Starting job GetActivities at 15:43 22/06/2016.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port XXXX
[statistics] connected
0X16000X00fQd61AAC|REI||
[statistics] disconnected
Job GetActivities ended at 15:43 22/06/2016. [exit code=0]
```

Is it possible to reference the subrows using Talend? If so, what is the syntax for the schema to do so? If not, how can I unpack this data in some ay to get to the `Description` fields for each `Account`? Any help is much appreciated.

Update: I have written a small [python script](https://gist.github.com/mtbdeano/2266f328126b2380f734c785c3e29bbc) to extract the `ActivityHistory` records and dump them in a file, then used a `tFileInput` to ingest the CSV and then continue through my process. But this seems *very* kludgey. Any better options out there?

Comment: We solved similar issue using two separate Salesforce Input component and tMap component

Comment: Thanks @LastKhajiit, i tried that as well but the sub-object (ActivityHistory) says "query is not supported on this type" and errors out.

Comment: hm, just checked ActivityHistory in Talend Salesforce Metadata it looks available like other SF objects (didn't try to extract ActivityHistory records).

Comment: Yup, it looks available, the metadata is correct, but I get the following when trying to query:  `com.salesforce.soap.partner.UnexpectedErrorFault: INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION: entity type ActivityHistory does not support query` which looks to be a Salesforce issue, not talend itself.

Comment: Just googled alittle - looks like it's really don't available for quering (only in subqueries). Seems, we went back to your approach described in question :)

Comment: I bump this question because I'm interesting in possible ways to solve it. Also you can add your solution with Python script as a Answer

Comment: thanks for your help @LastKhajiit, will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some debugging from the code perspective and it seems that if you specify correct column name, you will achieve the correct response. For your example, it should be: `Account_ActivityHistories_records_Description`

The output from tLogRow will be similar to:

```
00124000009gSHvAAM|Account1|tests;Lalalala
```

As you can see, the Description from all child elements are stored as 1 string, delimited by the semicolon. You can change the delimiter on Advanced Settings view on the SalesforceInput.

Comment: hmmm adding `_records_` is not mentioned anywhere, thanks for the debugging @vladykx this appears to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small python script ([source gist here](https://gist.github.com/mtbdeano/2266f328126b2380f734c785c3e29bbc)) to extract the `ActivityHistory` records and dump them in a file (command line argument), then used a `tFileInput` to ingest the CSV and then continue through my process.